# How do I qualify a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame using another SpatialPolygonsDataFrame?

Tags: r, gis, r-sp, census

I have Shapefiles from census data from US census.gov.

I've read the files into R using readOGR from the rdgal library.

**sp1**: voting district - SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

[image]

**sp2**: block level for a larger area and higher resolution than sp1 - SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

[image]

I have tried using gIntersection from the rgeos library, but it doesn't return what I need. Or I can't figure out how to use it properly

How do I extract the lower resolution polygons and associated data from sp2 using sp1 as a spacial restriction? In other words, I want to know all the blocks inside sp1 where sp1 and sp2 intersect.

**Current Working Solution**

The code below returns a vector of index values for sp2 where the polygon had at least one point inside sp1, but I wanted to know if there was an easier way.

```
library(rgeos)
result <- vector()
for (i in 1:nrow(sp2)) {
    if(gContains(sp1, sp2[i,])) {
        result <- c(result, i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
gContains(sp1, sp2, byid = TRUE)
```

for pair-wise contains relations for feature pairs.

```
sp2[sp1,]
```

selects those `sp2` features that intersect with `sp1`, but do read `vignette('over')` to find out about the limitations (it includes features that only touch).

Comment: The help documentation didn't make much sense, but setting byid = true does the trick. http://rpubs.com/washcycle/district99tabblockmap